# Clang format output errors

Tags: clang++, clang-format, clang-tidy

Is it possible to have clang-format issue output as warnings saying what to fix similar to clang tidy.
I would prefer to use clang-format due to the ease of setting up styles.

Answer (score 0):

Clang-format has the `-output-replacements-xml` option.

The xml output will tell you what changes and where to apply. You can then use it raw or parse it in any way that suits you.

Sample:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<replacements xml:space='preserve' incomplete_format='false'>
<replacement offset='337' length='8'>&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;  </replacement>
</replacements>
....etc
```